# I installed lubuntu desktop environments, now when I try to switch to Gnome the screen remain black

Tags: gnome, lubuntu, desktop-environments

I had Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome, I tried to add lubuntu desktop environments.

Now in the login screen (gdm3) I can change desktop environment in:

- Lubuntu
- Lxqt
- Openbox
- Ubuntu (which is Gnome)

When I try to use Gnome option, screen remain black, I can see the mouse cursor but everything is freeze and I can't neither use the terminal, I need to shut down manually everything.

Only few times I succeeded to load Gnome desktop.

I don't have this problem with other desktop options, they work fine.

Someone can explain what's going on?

Comment: It might help if you tell us how you added `lubuntu-desktop`.  I've added `lubuntu-desktop` onto many systems and never had issues (I usually opt to use `sddm` but cannot see how that would make a difference either).

Comment: I simply digited `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` . I don't have problem  switching  between lubuntu desktop enviroments, but when I try to use gnome, it won't load, I can't use it. @guiverc